# scrollIntoView behavior smooth not working on Ipad 8th gen

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, ipad, next.js

I have tried multiple solutions to achieve a smooth behavior on iPad 8th gen. like [iscroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iscroll), [react scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) and [custom polyfill scroll](https://medium.com/@snowleo208/how-to-create-smooth-scroll-for-your-website-ce5b198d9d94) as well but the behavior is instant instead of smooth.

onclick button :

```
<div className="mt-4 text-center mt-md-5 btn-hide">
 <Button className="btn-see-more btn-outline-light Event Based" size="lg" onClick={() => 
  executeScroll()}>
  {constants.SEE_MORE_BTN}
  </Button>
</div>
```

when i call the scroll function on button click,the scroll behavior is smooth on windows but when i have tested the same scroll on ipad 8th gen then the scroll behavior is instant.

```
 const executeScroll = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('discoverEvents');
    if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Use the `scroll-behavior` style object for body element. and check

Comment: Did you try this? [smoothscroll](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll)
Safari doesn't support options parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView